# nginx reverse proxy why am I still getting a certificate warning?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I'm running nginx via docker-compose. I've double checked that my ssl certs do indeed exist in `data/certbot/conf/live/collabora.mydomain.de/`

My docker-compose:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    container_name: collabora
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    cap_add:
      - MKNOD
    environment:
      - extra_params="--o:ssl.enable=false --o:ssl.termination=true"
      - domain=nx12345\.blah\.de
      - dictionaries=en_US
    ports:
      - "9980:9980"
    volumes:
      - ./appdata/collabora:/config    
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

And my nginx app.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.de;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name collabora.mydomain.de;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.mydomain.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/collabora.mydomain.de/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://collabora.mydomain.de;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    # WOPI discovery URL
    location ^~ /hosting/discovery {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9980;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # Capabilities
    location ^~ /hosting/capabilities {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9980;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # main websocket
    location ~ ^/lool/(.*)/ws$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9980;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    }

    # download, presentation and image upload
    location ~ ^/lool {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9980;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # Admin Console websocket
    location ^~ /lool/adminws {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9980;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    }
}
```

I run build and run the image `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up -d`

If I then visit https://collabora.mydomain.de (or even https://mydomain.de) I get a browser error (Firefox):

> Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

I'm not sure what other info to add.

Why is my ssl not working as expected and how can I configure it to be so?

[edit]
Here's the last couple of lines of output from `docker logs collabora` if it tells anything:

```
wsd-00009-00045 2021-03-02 12:37:57.132746 [ websrv_poll ] ERR  Socket #25 SSL BIO error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown (0: Success)| ./net/SslSocket.hpp:289
wsd-00009-00045 2021-03-02 12:37:57.132890 [ websrv_poll ] ERR  Error while handling poll for socket #25 in websrv_poll: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown| net/Socket.cpp:314
wsd-00009-00045 2021-03-02 12:45:02.705422 [ websrv_poll ] WRN  convert-to: Requesting address is denied: ::ffff:168.119.3.73| wsd/LOOLWSD.cpp:2315
```

Comment: Can you check why Firefox is saying it's security risk. There should be a button close to the warning, or it will be on the lock icon on the left of the url bar? Can also you check what the server is sending as a certificate chain with `openssl s_client -connect collabora.mydomain.de`.

Comment: Have you checked the certificates? Are they actually valid? Maybe the certbot container is failing somewhere along the way?

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski the full firefox message: `Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to mydomain.de. If you visit this site, attackers could try to steal information like your passwords, emails, or credit card details.

What can you do about it?

The issue is most likely with the website, and there is nothing you can do to resolve it.

If you are on a corporate network or using anti-virus software, you can reach out to the support teams for assistance. You can also notify the website’s administrator about the problem.`

Comment: 1) Check the certificate (if it is valid)
1) Check if the chain of trust is correct (with the `openssl` command I shared before)
1) Check if you have trust with the root CA on your machine (in cases where the certificate is signed by a private CA)

Comment: @AlexKarshin how would I verify that. I don't think so because, I got a 'congrats' message when running the script that generates the cert from let's encrypt. The script in question is the bash script over here: https://github.com/wmnnd/nginx-certbot

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski I'm new to this! How? How would one check if the certificate is valid?

Comment: Use `openssl` tools. Also if it's a `Letsencrypt` certificate, there could be problem with the chain of trust.

Comment: you can also check in this [thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/lets-encrypt-not-supporting-mozilla-firefox-for-some-verssions/109395) for certbot. There are known issues between firefox and certbot.

Comment: I get a similar error in firefox though `Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from collabora.mydomain.de (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski does this tell us anlything? https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=alamko.de

I got that link from the letsencrypt forum that you linked to

Comment: I'm trying to use a subdomain too collabora.mydomain.de, if that could be complicating it?

Comment: I've added some output of `docker logs collabora` too at the end of my post

Comment: I see the logs, you had not fetched the certificate. For you to get the certificate, `collabora.mydomain.de` needs to be on internet and the DNS should point to the IP address where you will run the server. The IP should be public IP.

Comment: Should I be checking `https://collabora.mydomain.de/` or `https://collabora.mydomain.de:9980`? In the dns manager for my provider I have double checked the domain name and ip mapping. The subdomain collabora.mydomain.de is there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can take a look at your certificate through the browser. Also you can take a look at `docker logs certbot`.

Comment: Also, on what OS are you running all this?

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far. I'm going to delete and repost with new information and a slightly different set up